# Badges cut off in top nav

Tags: bug, design

The top badge bullets are cut off on my Chrome browser. The bullet is clipped on the right side (see image below). This issue seems to be affecting all sites as I can see it happening here on Meta as well (strangely Meta badges are cut off on the left).

For the regular SO site the issue can be fixed by increasing the badge width from 6px to 8px. Not sure how that will look across all sites though. Also don't know if this issue is limited to Chrome or not.

[image]

Zoom 100%
Chrome 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)
OS Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (Build 7601.24468)

Comment: What's your zoom level? This can happen with CSS backgrounds at more than 100% zoom.

Comment: 100% (15 char filler text)

Comment: cannot reproduce, Chrome 75.0.3770.142 similar number of badges in all 3 columns.

Comment: @KevinB I was not referring to the number of badges. If you look at my screenshot provided they are flat on the right side because they are cut off. The width of their container is too small.

Comment: I'm aware, i was just pointing out that my numbers are similar to yours, so that didn't affect my result. (effectively ruling the badge count out.) The only way i can reproduce this is by zooming in or out.

Comment: Ah, understood. Added some extra info about versioning and zoom.

Comment: Where are you seeing that? Tried it in Firefox 68 and looked at a random question of yours on SO and it seemed fine. I'm not sure if that's where you noticed the issue and FF is OK or it's not and you noticed it elsewhere.

Comment: @VLAZ It's the badges in the top right nav. But... since you mentioned that I also looked at the badges on my questions and answers and the same issue is happening there as well because the same CSS class is applied in both cases (`.badge1, .badge2, .badge3`). I'm assuming the issue is happening wherever there are circular badges shown.